# Add img into react state for display in custom dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, drop-down-menu, state

**Goal**

I need to develop a single-select dropdown menu that allows the user to choose from different images instead of words.

**Background**

I've downloaded react dropdown and imported into the file. The dropdown is working if I use words but I haven't been successful in making it display images instead.

**What I've tried**

First, in this.state, I tried adding a relative path to the image file. This simply rendered that path (duh). Next, I tried adding the img tag with the src pointing to the location of the image I want to display. The result is an image that seems to indicate that an image is supposed to be there.

**Here is the code**

```
import React from 'react';
import './EventContainer.css';
import { Dropdown } from 'reactjs-dropdown-component';
import { dining } from './EventContainerIcons.js';

class EventContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      ...props.event,
      activityIcon: [
          {
            id: 0,
            title: <img src={dining} width="64" height="64" alt="dining icon" />,
            selected: false,
            key: 'activityIcon'
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Orange',
            selected: false,
            key: 'activityIcon'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Strawberry',
            selected: false,
            key: 'activityIcon'
          }
        ],
    };
  }

  handleTypeChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      type: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleTimeChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      time: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSummaryChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      summary: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleNotesChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      notes: e.target.value
    })
  }

  resetThenSet = (id, key) => {
    let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state[key]));
    temp.forEach(item => item.selected = false);
    temp[id].selected = true;
    this.setState({
      [key]: temp
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="eventContainer-flex">
        <Dropdown
          title="Event Type"
          list={this.state.activityIcon}
          resetThenSet={this.resetThenSet}
        />
        <div>
          <input
            type="time"
            value={this.state.time}
            onChange={this.handleTimeChange}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            className="textarea-font"
            placeholder="Write summary here"
            value={this.state.summary}
            onChange={this.handleSummaryChange}
            cols={60}
            rows={3} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            className="textarea-font"
            placeholder="Write notes here"
            value={this.state.notes}
            onChange={this.handleNotesChange}
            cols={30}
            rows={3} />
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default EventContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the image name into the import. like a

```
import image from './EventContainerIcons/dining.png';
```

after that,

```
title: <img src={image} alt="empty" />
```

FYI: while you use image add a alt attribute to img tag.

reference link: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-https-bkmf0

Comment: If I do that, I am able to select the image but if I select the same dropdown a second time the screen goes blank.

Comment: Thank you, I see that it's working in the sandbox but I can't replicate it. I edited my code (above). Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're the best.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation.